# AngularJS app.js cached in browser

Tags: angularjs, caching

Modern borwsers cache resources to improve loading performances. Images, javascrpits, css and other resources are cached by default and it could happen that the user have to clear the cache or hard refresh (CTRL+F5) to reload complitely the page and the resources.

AngularJS app are based on javascripts: controllers, services, filters, directives, app and so on.

During the develop of my application, I noticed that every time i reload the page, the browser automatically take the newest .js even if I link js as:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

without forcing the reload with the ver tip:

```
<script src="js/app.js?ver=1"></script>
```

If I modify a stylesheet and reload my page, the browser will reload the .css too.

How does it works? Is it something related to the **ng-app** directive?

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

I can't figure it out how does the browser cache/not cache resources.

Comment: it is not related to the ng-app directive. check the response headers of the resources the browser loads (firebug or developer console). I guess there ist something like Cache-Control:public, max-age=0 in the headers. what kind of server did you use?

Comment: Cache-Control:max-age=0 thanks!